# How to preview visualforce page using Mavensmate?

Tags: visualforce, mavensmate

I am new to programming and have installed and setup Mavensmate with Sublime text. Please advise what's the command for previewing a visualforce page, the equivalent of preview button on the visualforce page editor on developer console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such functionality in sublime or Mavansmate. Sublime is only a text editor which has no direct integration with Salesforce.

To use Sublime preview a web page, you can take a look at [this link](http://www.granneman.com/webdev/editors/sublime-text/set-up-sublime-text-to-preview-your-code-in-a-web-browser/). However, I don't think it will work for VF page though because the browser itself won't be able to understand those VF tags.

However, I don't think it is really a bit deal to me. To view the page, simply type [Your domain].salesforce.com/apex/[Your VF page name] into the browser, add you will be able to review it. Personally, I found it much easier to use than the preview button because you can add as many parameters as you want.

**Edit:**

As promised, I wrote a sublime plugin to support this feature. Please feel free to let me know if you have any issues with that. The link: [Github](https://github.com/Lanceshi2/VisualforcePreview) [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/VisualforcePreview)